# Liferay - Create API to extract data from Dynamic Data List

Tags: web-services, liferay, dynamic-data-list

Hi need to create create a webservice that would extract dinamically data from Liferay. Data is being inserted via Dynamic Data Lists.

Example:
1-I have one Dynamic Data List for clients
2-I have one Dynamic Data List for addresses

I want to create a web service that would receive via input the id of the list, and then, would dynamically return data in a specific format (xml, json, or whatever).

Comment: Is your question about the web service our about Liferay's api for ddl? What have you tried so far? Please show code

Comment: What hurdles do you face in your approach or any errors?